# Why can't I add this library dependency to my project?

Tags: android

https://github.com/isaaceindhoven/android-step-indicator

I added the gradle dependency to my `build.gradle` file

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'nl.isaac:android-step-indicator:1.0.1'
}
```

When I sync it, there's no issues. But when trying to add it to my xml file it can't find the package.

[image]

I've cleared and invalided the caches, cleaned and rebuilt project, but it's still not working.

Never ran into an issue like this before.

Build output:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find nl.isaac:android-step-indicator:1.0.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/nl/isaac/android-step-indicator/1.0.1/android-step-indicator-1.0.1.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/nl/isaac/android-step-indicator/1.0.1/android-step-indicator-1.0.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Means that the download link was removed and is no longer available/supported. You got 2 choices if you want to use the library:

1. Re-Upload the project to one of the repositories (you need author's consent)
2. Download the content and insert the files into the project instead of implementation.

Comment: Why would they remove the download link and keep the github repo up with no deprecated label or anything

Comment: Could have been that the project didn't meet the new requirements of the library and thus was deleted.

Comment: Interesting. One of the most popular crypto apps on the playstore uses this exact library and I'm surprised it's removed.